# how to fix missing API-MS-ONECOREUAP-SETTINGSYNC-STATUS-L1-1-0.DLL?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

Dependency Walker tells this  API-MS-ONECOREUAP-SETTINGSYNC-STATUS-L1-1-0.DLL and a bunch of other DLLs are missing and I don't know how to fix it. How can I find them and what should I do exactly?
[image]
[image]
as you see it's a lot of them
[image]

renderdoc.dll is created after building the project in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition with x64 and Debug settings for configuration and also in Windows 10 Home Edition 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to fix this. The only missing library that prevents `renderdoc.dll` from being loaded correctly is `IlmImf.dll` and `zlibd.dll`. You have built `IlmImf.dll` in order to successfully compile `renderdoc.dll`, but it is not located in any of the directories in which your application is looking for libraries. You need to find the directory in which `IlmImf.dll` resides and add this directory to your PATH environment variable. `IlmImf.dll` has dependencies by itself, so you better double-check with dependency walker again after editing your `PATH` variable.
In the `PATH` I added the path to `renderdoc.dll`, `IlmImf.dll` and `zlibd.dll`
[image]